# Seaborn colorbar height to match heatmap

Tags: pandas, seaborn

There are a few examples showing how to use "shrink" for changing the colorbar. How can I automatically figure out what the shrink should be so the colorbar is equal to the height of the heatmap?

I don't have a matplotlib axis because I am using seaborn and plotting the heatmap from the dataframe.

```
    r = []
    r.append(np.arange(0,1,.1))
    r.append(np.arange(0,1,.1))
    r.append(np.arange(0,1,.1))
    df_cm = pd.DataFrame(r)

    sns.heatmap(df_cm, square=True, cbar_kws=dict(ticks=[df_cm.min().min(), df_cm.max().max()]))
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig(f'test.png', bbox_inches="tight")
```

[image]

Comment: If you set `square=False` (the default), the colorbar will automatically have the correct size.

Comment: @JohanC yes but I need it square

Comment: @JohanC Sorry about that, added.

Comment: You get access to the matplotlib axis via `ax = sns.heatmap(....)`. You'll need to first create the heatmap without colorbar, then create a "colorbar `ax` " for the colorbar (e.g. via `make_axes_locatable`), and then create the colorbar on the newly created ax.

Comment: @JohanC It would be great if you could make an answer out of that.  It seems I need to change up everything as the return from sns doesn't have `get_array`

Comment: You could use `plt.colorbar(ax.collections[0], cax= ..., ticks=...)`.  Note that `tight_layout` doesn't work if  you have this kind of relation between the `ax`es.